# CSS: font statement causes line-height not to work

Tags: html, css

I can't understand one thing in CSS.

As I understand, line-height is often used as a hack for middle vertical aligning.
In one situation it didn't work and only after thorough experimentation I found the cause, which is rather incomprehensible and annoying to me.

So what is the problem?

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ejRA3/

```
#outer, #outer-bug {
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#outer-bug {
    font: bold 15px Arial;
}

#outer {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Both divs have exactly the same CSS properties, they only differ in one thing. One has font properties in font statement, while second has three font-... statements.

Yet, in the one with font statement, text is magically not in the middle.

So can someone pinpoint the reason to me, why has font this weird effect? Or is it just bug (improbable as it happens in all 3 major browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Opera)?

Thanks for all good explanations or at least attempts of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no bug, it's the way you are declaring the short hand syntax is resetting the `line-height`

```
#outer-bug {
    font: bold 15px/32px Arial;
               /* ---^--- line-height */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejRA3/2/)

Here's an handy chart to refer

[image]

<sup>[Credits for the chart](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/)</sup>

---

The `line-height` is an optional parameter there... Using Firebug you can make out that your `line-height` is overridden because `#outer-bug` block is written after `#outer, #outer-bug`.

[image]

Swapping them will solve the issue as well

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejRA3/3/) *(Swapped property blocked declarations)*

Comment: @oGeez Upvoted yours as well, never knew there was another one with the same answer as I am busy editing :D

Comment: Thank you both.
I would be glad to give you upvotes, but unfortunately I don't yet have high enough reputation.

Comment: @juraj I know and you posted an elaborated question so I've upvoted the question and It's fine, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

When the `font` style is given, a `line-height` comes with the font size part of it - if it's not specified it will be `normal`. You can change what the line height gets set to by adding `/n` after your font's size:

```
#outer-bug {
    font: bold 15px/35px Arial;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/ejRA3/1/)